# Does the Federation administer any non-Federation space stations other than Deep Space Nine?

Tags: star-trek, federation, space-station

One of the interesting plot points in *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* was that the titular space station was *administered* by the Federation but was otherwise not a Federation facility (built by the Cardassians and owned by the Bajorans, neither being Federation members). This made for some interesting politics that would likely not have been present on a "pure" Federation starbase.

So, is Deep Space Nine the *only* non-Federation starbase under Federation administration, or are there others?

Caveats:

- Stations built by a Federation member world prior to joining the Federation do not count. So, an old Andorian space station recommissioned as a Federation Starbase after the founding of the Federation does not count.
- Stations temporarily occupied as part of a military maneuver do not count unless the Federation "settles down" there indefinitely or at least for an extended period of time beyond that necessary for immediate military goals. If Starfleet personnel invaded and temporarily occupied a Romulan space station only as long as necessary to steal some blueprints and then escape, that would not count. If they continued to occupy the station and recommissioned it as a Federation asset to be used indefinitely for future operations, that *would* count.

More generally, the question is whether the situation with DS9 is unique, or whether it is common for various non-Federation (but perhaps wannabe member) civilizations to request that Starfleet come in and administer their stations for them.

In response to a comment by DoscoJones, Deep Space Station K-7 is a Federation facility. While Klingons are apparently sometimes allowed to dock there and visit its recreational facilities, that doesn't make it a Klingon space station under Federation administration.

Comment: @DoscoJones K-7 is a Federation starbase.

Comment: Edit: So far as I can remember, K-7 is the only other deep space station ever detailed.  This question may not be answerable.

Comment: @DoscoJones I'm not asking about "Deep Space" stations, I'm asking about non-Federation stations administered by the Federation. These might be Deep Space stations or not.